# Telerik RadChart autosize x-axis labels (non-numeric)

Tags: telerik, styling, radchart

I have DataBind(ed) a RadChart, and the x-axis values are non-numeric (text).  I have already added XAxis-Appearance-LabelAppearance-RotationAngle="45" to better display the x-axis labels.  I am unable to find a way to make the space that contains the x-axis labels autosize.  Is this possible?

example (the rotation works, the others were my unsuccessful attempts at autosizing the label area):

```
<telerik:RadChart ID="RadChart1" runat="server" Width="600px">
<PlotArea XAxis-Appearance=LabelAppearance-Dimensions-AutoSize="true"
  XAxis-Appearance-LabelAppearance-RotationAngle="45"
  Appearance-Dimensions-AutoSize="true"
</Plot Area>
</telerik:RadChart>
```

Thanks!

Comment: I was able to accomplish this by setting the PlotArea-Appearance-Dimensions-Margins.